# How do I apply an attribute to a single type in an inheritance tree?

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, attributes, json.net

This question is focused towards my specific issue, but I feel there's a bigger problem here that needs to be addressed.

Using the JSON.NET library, I'm trying to deserialize a complex JSON type to a .NET object model with an inheritance tree.
Because the type of the document cannot be determined at compile time, I wrote my own converter that determines the type based on a JSON property value.

To keep it short, my object model has a structure that resembles the following:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonVehicleConverter))]
abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}

class Bike : Vehicle
{
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int Doors { get; set; }
}
```

Looking at the model above, I'd think I can deserialize my document like this:

```
string json = @"{
                    ""type"": ""car"",
                    ""wheels"": 4,
                    ""doors"": 2
                }";

Vehicle vehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vehicle>(json);
```

My custom converter would then go ahead and parse the value, then decide which implementation to use:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jsonObject = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);

    var type = jsonObject.Value<string>("type");

    if (type == "bike")
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<Bike>(jsonObject.CreateReader());
    }
    else if (type == "car")
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<Car>(jsonObject.CreateReader());
    }
}
```

**The problem** however, is that `Bike` and `Car` **inherit the attribute** that tells the serializer which converter to use.

The result of that is that JSON.NET will forever be stuck in a `ReadJson` loop, resulting in a `StackOverflowException` (how appropriate).

So the question is: how do I apply an attribute to an abstract class, in a way that the sub-classes do not inherit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the attribute to not be inherited?

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All,
 AllowMultiple = false,
 Inherited = false)]
public JsonVehicleConverterAttribute : System.Attribute
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: The converter itself is not an attribute, but I think you're on to something!

Comment: you could create an attribute and then search for the attribute thru the entire inheritance chain when trying to determine the serializer/deserializer.

Comment: Gahh!! They sealed the JsonConverterAttribute. :(

Comment: You put me back on the right track with the `AttributeUsageAttribute`, but unfortunately I can't override it because the [JsonConverterAttribute](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConverterAttribute.cs?source=cc) is sealed. What are my options?

Comment: I have an idea, does the Deserializer handle the IDeserializationCallback?  If you implement this interface on the Abstract class does it fire it?  If so you could have a private bool variable in the abstract class that upon "OnDeserialization" you could check to see if you have already been deser'd

Comment: I think the problem with this is that the deserializer is stuck infinitely trying to find an appropriate converter. My object is never actually deserialized.

Comment: ok crazy idea here, what if you create another CustomConverter? You have the one that is working on the abstract, if you create a bogus converter and apply that to the sub classes?  Would that stop the chain or would that trump the abstract?

Comment: I thought about doing that, but it feels hacky. I think that would work though.

Comment: I ended up writing a `DefaultConverter` that has `CanRead == CanWrite == false` just for the purpose of forcing the serializer to not use a converter at all. It's a hack, but it's not all that ugly.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this issue is not to place an attribute on the class, but instead pass an instance of the converter to the `DeserializeObject` method.

```
Vehicle vehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vehicle>(json,
                                                     new JsonVehicleConverter);
```

Then, in your `ReadJson` method in the converter, don't use the serializer passed to the method to create the object instances.  Instead use `ToObject<T>`:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jsonObject = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);

    var type = jsonObject.Value<string>("type");

    if (type == "bike")
    {
        return jsonObject.ToObject<Bike>();
    }
    else if (type == "car")
    {
        return jsonObject.ToObject<Car>();
    }

    throw new JsonSerializationException();
}
```

Finally, make sure that the `CanConvert` method is implemented correctly, if it isn't already:

```
public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    return typeof(Vehicle).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. This makes me wonder if there are any other ways to specify a JSON converter other than setting the attribute. This solution is a bit _too_ loosely coupled for me.

Comment: Seems that I can also create a serializer "contract" that optionally sets a converter depending on the `objectType`. Very interesting stuff.

Comment: Yes, that may be another approach you could take.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you want to inherit it but it is a variable only in the abstract class and becomes an invariant for the subclass. You can do this to force the invariant to be correctly initialized:

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    protected string _type;

    public int Wheels { get; set; }

    public Vehicle(string type)
    {
        this._type = type;
    }
}

class Bike : Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    : base("Bike")
    {
        // no implementation
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle
{
    public int Doors { get; set; }

    public Vehicle()
    : base("Car")
    {
        // no implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a similar approach working using a ThreadLocal static variable on my converter class. The approach smells wrong, but does appear to work.

In my converter class I have a static ThreadLocal variable

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<int> nesting = new ThreadLocal<int>();
```

In my CanRead property I test this

```
public override bool CanRead { get { return nesting.Value == 0; } }
```

And I increment it in my ReadJson method

```
nesting.Value = nesting.Value + 1;
try {
  ....
}
finally {
    nesting.Value = nesting.Value - 1;
}
```

So far in my simple testing it appears to work ok.